# Laravel - track URL / pageviews

Tags: laravel, filter, middleware, tracking

I want to know whether a user visited the page or not. And, if the user had visited the page, I want to display it like **"Last seen on Apr 16"**

I heard `before` and `after` filters are now replaced by **Middleware**.

How can I achieve this? ***I'm on Laravel 5.6***

**Route**

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'Controller@view')->name('view')->where('url', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($url, request $id)
  {
   $item = Item::where('url', $url)->firstorfail();
   return  view ('view');
  }
```

**View Blade**

```
@extends('layout')

@section ('content')
 This page is last visited on Apr 16
@endsection
```

Comment: I would use a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers) with a session. It’s a bit long-winded to put in an answer, but use that as a starter for 10 for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need this, but anyhow:

What you should use is middleware with parameter: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#middleware-parameters

and you will have to group your routes like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'module:supplier'], function () {
    Route::any('supplier/{id}', 'SupplierController@supplier');
    Route::any('suppinv/{invoice}/{order}', 'SuppInvController@suppinv');
    Route::get('suppord/{id}', 'SuppOrdController@suppord');
});
```

Then you have to update your table you will need middleware like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $module)
{
    DB::table('table_name')->insert(['user_id' => Auth::id(),'module' => $module, 'date_time' => Carbon::now()->toDateString()]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

You could also check if user already has accessed page and update record instead of inserting new if you don't need some kind a tracking possibilities.

Everything else you can figure out on your own by provided link.

Ask if you have any questions, I'll try to replay as soon as I can.

Comment: Should I make a separate function for this as you mentioned or I can add to my show function?

Comment: @universal it all should be a single function in your custom middleware

Comment: Totally baffled (newbie). I added your function code to my show function. It returned ``Closure does not exist``. I added middleware ``auth:user``, then ``Auth guard [user] not found``

Comment: That function has to go in Middleware and has to be changed to fit your app. I think you should read how middleware works and basics like Routing and Authentication from Laravel docs first and then proceed. I can't teach you whole framework to help fix your issue